# Why array[array.length] returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to access the last value of an array, but don't understand why this doesn't work.

```
const arr = [2 , 3, 6, 8];
const end = arr[ arr.length ];
console.log(end);
```

But when I try console logging the value it returns 4, which is what I was looking for with previous code :

```
console.log(arr.length);
```

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed, so the indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3  if you want the last element it's `arr[arr.length -1]`

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed so you might want to think about what that means for the arr.length..

Comment: last array of element is at index `length -1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are **zero-based** indexing. Which means The first element of the array is indexed by subscript of 0 and last element will be `length - 1`

```js
const arr = [2 , 3, 6, 8];
const end = arr[ arr.length - 1 ];
console.log(end);
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript array indexes start counting at 0.  So...

`arr[0]` evaluates to `2`

`arr[1]` evaluates to `3`

`arr[2]` evaluates to `6`

`arr[3]` evaluates to `8`

`arr.length` evaluates to `4` because there are 4 elements in your array

`arr[4]` refers to the 5th element in an array, which in your example, is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are 0-indexed. The last item of the array can be accessed with `arr[arr.length - 1]`. In your example, you're attempting to access an element at an index that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

`Array` index always start with 0 and `Array length` is equal to counts of element in array

```
value   => [2,3,6,8]
indexes => [0,1,2,3]
```

that is why `arr[4]` coming `undefined` because there is not value at index 4.

```js
const arr = [2 , 3, 6, 8];
const end = arr[ arr.length-1 ];
console.log(end);
```